# How to change kernel when Jupyter notebook shows only one Python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I need to change the kernel to point it to miniconda version of Python, but Jupyter Notebook shows only one "Python 3" under Kernel-> Change Kernel.

Any idea how to get Jupyter notebook to show the additional one installed?

Comment: Try this answer, it worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47262847/4584857

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this and install the required kernel

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manually configure (add) `Python 2.7` environment, try this:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
conda activate py27
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user
```

Answer (score 0):

More generally, for a kernel to show up in Jupyter, it must be [registered in a known location](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernels.html#kernelspecs).

If you're in a python environment with ipykernel installed, run a command like this to register it ([docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments)):

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name my-env --display-name "Python (my-env)"
```