# Unable to register/access/use conda virtual enviroment in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda

There are a lot of questions related to this on SO, however all the answers appear not to work for me.

**The problem:**

I have a conda environment, called rideaux. I wish to access this enviroment from my jupyter notebooks. However, in jupyter notebooks the only kernel available is the default one.

[image]

To test, I tried to import packages that are available in the conda environment, but as expected this does not work in the available kernel.

**What I tried:**

As per related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191297/how-to-switch-environment-on-jupyter-notebook-for-new-notebook) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068818/how-to-use-jupyter-notebooks-in-a-conda-environment) (and more not listed here).

1. First, I tried to simply run the jupyter notebook server from inside the rideaux enviroment.
   This returns no change from the image above, i.e., the rideaux kernel is not available.
2. Next, I tried to use the `nb_conda_kernels` package. I installed `conda install -n notebook_env nb_conda_kernels` in my base environment and in my rideaux environment. I also installed `ipykernel` in my rideaux environment `conda install ipykernel`. Then, started a notebook server from the rideaux environment resulted in no change from the image above.
3. I tried to register the conda environment by running `ipython kernel install --user --name=rideaux` while inside the rideaux environment. This resulted in no change.

**General information and troubleshooting.**

Running `which jupyter` within the rideaux environment returns a executable from inside the environment.

Running `jupyter kernelspec list` returns the following. Here `python3` appears to be the one seen in the image above. Then why does the rideaux kernel not show up?

```
Available kernels:
  rideaux    /home/mjpvanzuijlen/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/rideaux
  python3    /home/mjpvanzuijlen/anaconda3/envs/rideaux/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Running `!jupyter-troubleshoot` inside the notebook returns the output below. Nowhere does it mention the `rideaux` environment and the one returned by `which jupyter` is also not visible here. This might mean the wrong jupyter is being ran? I am not sure.

```
$PATH:
    /snap/jupyter/6/bin
    /snap/jupyter/6/usr/sbin
    /snap/jupyter/6/usr/bin
    /snap/jupyter/6/sbin
    /snap/jupyter/6/bin
    /home/mjpvanzuijlen/snap/jupyter/common/bin
    /usr/local/sbin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/sbin
    /usr/bin
    /sbin
    /bin
    /usr/games
    /usr/local/games

sys.path:
    /snap/jupyter/6/bin
    /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python37.zip
    /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7
    /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
    /snap/jupyter/6/lib/python3.7/site-packages

sys.executable:
    /snap/jupyter/6/bin/python3.7

sys.version:
    3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:01:00) 
    [GCC 7.3.0]

platform.platform():
    Linux-4.15.0-140-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.10

which -a jupyter:
    /snap/jupyter/6/bin/jupyter
    /snap/jupyter/6/bin/jupyter
```

Comment: Install `nb_conda_kernels` and `jupyter` in one environment, and always launch `jupyter notebook` with that environment active (sounds like your **base**). Kernel environments only need `ipykernel`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/570918); also [the `nb_conda_kernels` README](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels#readme) is worth a read.